# How does sulfuric acid react to heating?

Tags: safety, heat

How would $\ce{H2SO4}$ react to heat? I assume that it would form toxic sulfur (di/tri)oxide, but I can't find any information on this.

I'm concerned about fire hazards specifically, so assume very intense heating and very low concentration.

Comment: "very low concentration"? Then that's slightly acidic water and there's  not much difference what acid is there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sulfuric acid, $\ce{H2SO4}$, having an enthalpy of formation of $-814\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$, is quite stable and won't decompose easily.

According to [*A Kinetic Study of the Decomposition of Spent Sulfuric Acids at High Temperature, Dominique Schwartz, Roger Gadiou, Jean-François Brilhac, Gilles Prado, and Ginès Martinez*](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ie990801e?journalCode=iecred):

> The decomposition of $\ce{H2SO4}$ to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{SO3}$ is predominant between $400$ and $700\ \mathrm K$. The formation of a small amount of gaseous sulfuric acid can be observed. Above $673\ \mathrm K$, the equilibrium constant of the reaction R1 becomes higher than 1 and increases rapidly.
>
> $$\ce{H2SO4 <=> H2O + SO3}\tag{R1}$$
>
> The second process is the reduction of sulfur trioxide to $\ce{SO2}$. This endothermic reaction needs a high temperature to take place, the equilibrium constant of the reaction R2 being higher than 1 above $1050\ \mathrm K$.
>
> $$\ce{SO3 <=> SO2 + \dfrac12O2}\tag{R2}$$

So, you only have to worry when the temperature reaches $400\ \mathrm K$, or $127\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ ([false precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision)).

Comment: @YdobEmos Usually available sulfuric acid is dissolved in water (except sulfuric acid in which case there is little water), so the temperature would be limited by the water.

Comment: In aqueous solution, you also have to worry about the water boiling and spitting acid at you. A speck of hot sulphuric acid on a mucus membrane is not a pleasant experience.

Answer (score 7):

First, you don't need to worry about fire: sulphuric acid is non-flammable.

Around $1000$ kelvin, this reaction would occur:

$$\ce{2H2SO4 <=> 2SO2 + 2H2O + O2}$$

This is industrially used for the production of hydrogen gas, and the total reaction cycle is called the [sulphur-iodine cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur%E2%80%93iodine_cycle).