# Why mixture turns brown upon heating, during esterification with H2SO4?

Tags: catalysis, reaction-control, esters

In the lab I was synthesising an ester with sulphuric acid as a catalyst. However the mixture turned brown and my teacher said I had burnt the acid, but what does this actually mean?

Comment: It might be worth adding some details on the process you were using to make the ester, describing it as burning the acid sounds a little unusual on his part.

Comment: I was heating the mixture under reflux but he said i was heating it too strong and as a result i 'burnt' the acid

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60708/how-does-sulfuric-acid-react-to-heating

Comment: It isn't acid, but rest of mixture that was damaged by H2SO4 if you overheat.

Comment: what damage will be taking place then?